# Replay request or copy request as CURL in Flutter DevTools

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

Is there a way to copy the HTTP request as a curl command (colloquially, "copy as curl") or to replay it from the network developer tools for Flutter?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419760/is-there-a-minimum-length-to-consider-a-question-as-a-good-one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest devtools versions should have the copy-as-`curl` functionality. See the [PR here](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/pull/4113).

See also the feature request issue that the above PR closed: *[feature request: copy http request "as curl" #3042](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3042)*

According to [the CHANGELOG](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2140) the feature was released in version **2.14.0**, so in theory you just have to upgrade to that or any later version, and you'll have *Copy as URL* and *Copy cURL*.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot copy a request as curl in dev tools. If you use [Dio](https://blog.logrocket.com/networking-flutter-using-dio/), you can intercept the Dio request with [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/curl_logger_dio_interceptor) and get an HTTPS request as a curl string printed in the console. Then you can use [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) to replay it.